# Bash * directory wildcard not working in if statement using double brackets

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards, test

This works:

```
if  [ /a/*/b/file.asd -nt  /c/d/file.asd ]; then echo "found new file"; fi
```

This doesn't work:

```
if  [[ /a/*/b/file.asd -nt  /c/d/file.asd ]]; then echo "found new file"; fi
```

Can someone please explain why `/*/` is not working with double brackets?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-double-square-brackets-preferable-over-single-square-brackets-in-ba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell globbing patterns potentially expand to more than one pathname.  For example, if `/a/*/b/file.asd` expands to multiple pathnames, then the test that you are performing becomes nonsensical.

Also, shell globs are *not* expanded inside `[[ ... ]]`. From the `bash` manual:

> Word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed on the
>   words between the `[[` and `]]`

If you know that you want to perform the test on a *particular* file, e.g. `/a/x/b/file.asd`, then use that pathname in the test.  If you want to perform the test on *all* pathnames that matches that pattern, use a loop:

```bash
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
for pathname in /a/*/b/file.asd; do
    if [[ $pathname -nt /c/d/file.asd ]]; then
        printf 'found new file: %s\n' "$pathname"
    fi
done
```

The `nullglob` and `dotglob` shell options are set so that the pattern is removed if it does not match anything and so that `*` catches any hidden directories.

Also, the test could be done with `find`, unless the pattern `/a/*/b/file.asd` expands to many thousands of pathnames:

```
find /a/*/b/file.asd -prune -type f -newer /c/d/file.asd
```

This would expand the pattern `/a/*/b/file.asd` and use each of the pathnames that it expands to as a search path for `find`.  The search paths are tested against `/c/d/file.asd` and the pathnames are printed if they are newer than that file.  The `-prune` stops `find` from moving down into a search path, just in case any of them refers to a directory.

Comment: As i said in my post that the statement with single brackets WORKS, it actually checks all path names :)

Comment: @r.tihovs It can't, unless the pattern only ever expands to a single pathname.  You'll get an error if it expands to multiple pathnames.

Comment: Yes indeed, the name is the same always, only the directory is changing

Comment: So in conclusion im interested why shell globs are not expanded inside [[ ... ]]. Can you please explain?

Comment: @r.tihovs It's not much to explain really. Bash just does not do pathname expansion inside `[[ ... ]]`.  I've added the relevant quote from the `bash` manual.

Comment: `-name file.asd` is redundant since it's going to be true for each of those files.

Comment: @r.tihovs, it's for the same reason that word-splitting isn't performed for unquoted variables inside `[[ .. ]]`. Both can produce multiple words, which would mess up the test syntax completely, as they can do, and _do_ do with `[ .. ]`. There's a number of questions here on site where a `[ .. ]` test goes wrong when a variable is used unquoted. E.g. do you know what `[ -n $a ]` does when `a` contains zero or more than one word? Nobody _wants_ it that way, so the `[[ .. ]]` tosses that kind of historical silliness away.

Comment: I suppose one could use something like `find /a -path "/a/*/b/file.asd" -prune -type f -newer /c/d/file.asd` to deal with the case where all the pathnames don't fit in the arguments of a single command, but that's hopefully not needed.

Comment: @ilkkachu There are a _few_ ways to skin this cat, yes.

Comment: Thanks everyone, now i know that globbing with double brackets isnt supported, my script works fine with single brackets, it just left me curios. To better understand what im doing, i have many sftp clients with different chroot home directories, each of these clients are uploading a backup file each night with a particular store code in its name, so my script loops all store codes and searches for latest backup files and processes them.